# Android - stretched preview from front facing camera

Tags: android, camera

I implemented camera app as recommended here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html but when I try to use front facing camera (on my device it has VGA resolution) the preview image is stretched.

I also tried to refer to `CameraPreview.java` sample in APIDemos which is supposed to be aspect ratio independent but image is stretched there too.

How to fix it?

Oh, I would also add that when I'm using Android camera app everything is fine...

Comment: Is the issue resolved ?

Comment: @Vishal Vyas I kinda went to other things, but I believe you have to manually resize your `SurfaceView` to fit required aspect ratio (you have to make sure there is no automatic sizing going on (like with "match_parent" attribute or similar...)).

Comment: Can u please tell , how did you resolve this issue?? i am facing the same problem. @mrpyo